# How to draw a monochrome image onto a canvas, but use a different color?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have an image which is black and white. If necessary, I can transform it into transparent and white.

How can I draw this image onto a canvas, replacing white with an arbitrary color?

I want to be able to draw text onto a canvas using a font like the below, using different colors. I don't want to have multiple copies of the image.

[image: CPC 464 Font]

Comment: I think with the white background/transparent foreground form you can first draw a rectangle behind the spot you want to write to and then apply the image on top of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this.

### Offscreen

Create an off-screen canvas,  <strike>render the the text to that canvas and then use  `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "color"`</strike> (update my bad that should be `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in"`) draw the color first then draw the text over the color. (see example)

#### Example of above method

```js
canvas.width = 430;
canvas.height = 16;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// off screen canvas
const text = document.createElement("canvas");
text.width = 512;
text.height = 16;
text.ctx = text.getContext("2d");

const font = new Image;
font.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXaVG.png"
font.addEventListener("load", () => {
    drawColorString("000Black text#F00 Red text#FF0 Yellow#0F0 Green#0FF Cyan#00F Blue#F0F Magenta", 10, 4);
});
const grad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
grad.addColorStop(0,"#FFF");
grad.addColorStop(1,"#000");
ctx.fillStyle = grad;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

function drawColorString(str, xpos, ypos) {
    const parts = str.split("#");
    var x = 0;
    for (const part of parts) {
        const color = part.slice(0,3);
        const chars = part.slice(3);
        for (const char of chars) {
            drawChar(char, color, x);
            x += 8;
        }
    }
    colorText();
    ctx.drawImage(text, xpos, ypos);
}
function colorText() {
    text.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
    text.ctx.drawImage(text, 0, 8, text.width, 8, 0, 0, text.width, 8);
    text.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
}
function drawChar(char, color, xpos) {
    const c = char.charCodeAt(0);
    const x = (c % 32) * 8;
    const y = (c / 32 | 0) * 8;
    
    text.ctx.fillStyle = "#" + color;
    text.ctx.fillRect(xpos, 0, 8, 8);
    text.ctx.drawImage(font, x, y, 8, 8, xpos, 8, 8, 8);
 }
```

```css
canvas {
    border:1px solid black;

}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

#### Font image used

[image: Example of masked font]

### Additive

Second way is to modify the source image to give you masked Black, Red, Green, Blue versions of the text. The to render a color, draw the black text, then overlay using `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter"`to add the r,g,b amounts as needed.

#### Example of additive method

```js
canvas.width = 430;
canvas.height = 16;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const font = new Image;
font.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfGjd.png"
font.addEventListener("load", () => {

    drawColorString("000Black text#F00 Red text#FF0 Yellow#0F0 Green#0FF Cyan#00F Blue#F0F Magenta", 10, 4);
});
const grad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
grad.addColorStop(0,"#FFF");
grad.addColorStop(1,"#000");
ctx.fillStyle = grad;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

function drawColorString(str, x, y) {
    const parts = str.split("#");
    for (const part of parts) {
        const color = part.slice(0,3);
        const chars = part.slice(3);
        for (const char of chars) {
            drawChar(char, color, x, y);
            x += 8;
        }
    }
}
function drawChar(char, color, xpos, ypos) {
    const addLayer = (channel, amount) => {
        if (amount) {
            ctx.globalAlpha = amount;
            ctx.drawImage(font, x, y + 64 * (channel + 1), 8, 8, xpos, ypos, 8, 8);
        }
    }
    const red   = parseInt(color[0] + color[0], 16) / 255; 
    const green = parseInt(color[1] + color[1], 16) / 255; 
    const blue  = parseInt(color[2] + color[2], 16) / 255; 
    const c = char.charCodeAt(0);
    const x = (c % 32) * 8;
    const y = (c / 32 | 0) * 8;
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.drawImage(font, x, y, 8, 8, xpos, ypos, 8, 8);

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter"; 
    addLayer(0, red);
    addLayer(1, green);
    addLayer(2, blue);
    
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"; // default
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
 }
```

```css
canvas {
    border:1px solid black;

}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Example of the image used in above snippet.

[image: Example of RGB font]

Or you can combine the two methods and use the additive method to render coloured text to an offscreen canvas and then draw that canvas to the display canvas. That means you need only draw the text when it changes, not every frame if animated.

Comment: Good use of `globalCompositeOperation`, bravo!

Comment: Works for me! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

- The easiest way to do this is to replace the white in your image with a transparent "hole" where you want the colour, then use `.fillstyle` to change the background of the canvas.
- Save the image as a png, open some photo editing software, and take rub out a hole in the image where you want the colouring to be so you see the checkered transparent background.
- Move this file to wherever you store images in your project.
- add the image to your canvas element, make sure it fills the whole canvas. Use the following code to change the background of your canvas:

`let canvas = document.getElementByID("colourthis")
 let ctx = canvas.getContext("2D")
 ctx.fillstyle = 'red'`

- The transparent parts of the image will now be red.
- You could use some kind of randomizer to achieve the other colors.
- use `ctx.fillStyle = "transparent"` to get the transparent background.

Thats the way I would do this in vanilla JS, no JQuery or anything. There are other ways but judging by the tags you used I doubt you are using any plugins for this sort of thing.